# How to have an image span whole page in tumblr theme?

Tags: tumblr

As the title says, I'm wondering how to get this image to span the whole browser window/page instead of having the gray margins.

Im using this theme:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/olleota/themes/master/paperweight/main.html

And, its in action here:
http://fvcking5hit.tumblr.com/
where you see the gray borders and I just want it to span the whole page wile keeping the fade effect.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want any border/margin for the whole theme, or that you want the header image to fill the entire page as a background (with the post content on top).

Comment: I want to keep the margin, around the posts, and keep it gray, I just want the header photo to be across the whole page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK thank you for the additional comment, this should be all the code you need.

Find this code in your theme (it's showing at around line 226):

```
#masthead {
    margin: 0 10%;
    padding: 15% 0;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Change it to:

```
#masthead {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15% 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

There are several references to `#masthead` in your css, so you will need to target the last reference for this to work (or tidy up the css by removing the old properties).

**UPDATE**

As you pointed out there is a media query changing the properties of the masthead.

Find this code:

```
@media (min-width: 1500px){
  .theme-name-Paperweight #masthead {
     margin: 0 20%;
     width: 60%;
     padding: 10% 0;
  }
}
```

And change to:

```
@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  .theme-name-Paperweight #masthead {
     margin: 0;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 10% 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: This works for the most part, but when I pop it into fullscreen the margins come back... any fix?

Comment: OK that is in a css media query. Let me update my answer.